# Android LocalBroadcastManger not always receive data

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, localbroadcastmanager

I have a fragment with `TextView`. From the different places of my app I want to update that `TextView`, so I'm using `LocalBroadcastManager` but it is not always working - In fact when I disable device administrator (this is MDM app) it 'forget' to receive data...

```
    public static void sendMessage(String message) {
        MESSAGE = message;
        Intent intent = new Intent(MESSAGE_INTENT_FILTER);
        intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_EXTRA, message);
        App.getAppContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

`App.getAppContext()` is a static context declared in my Application class.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateStatus(MESSAGE);
}
```

In `onResume()` I'm updating stored message (because my fragment isn't always appeared.

my Receiver:

```
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String message = intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_EXTRA);
            updateStatus(message);
        }
    };
```

onStart / onStop:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    initReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MESSAGE_INTENT_FILTER);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(App.getAppContext()).registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(App.getAppContext()).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

my logs:

> on start fragment
>
> on resume fragment - message: Message 1
>
> update status - message: Message 1
>
> send message: Message 2
>
> on stop fragment
>
> on start fragment
>
> on resume fragment - message: Message 2
>
> update status - message: Message 2
>
> **DISABLED ADMIN**
>
> send message: Cancel

And thats it... no more receive

Comment: You're sending the intent with  the extra being stored in `MESSAGE_KEY`, but retrieving it with `MESSAGE_EXTRA`, is this normal?

Comment: If you want Receivers registered with `LocalBroadcastManager` to get broadcasts, you need to send them with `LocalBroadcastManager`. That is, `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);`.

Comment: Its was a mistake with copy-paste - it is `MESSAGE_EXTRA` in my code - edited...